# How to install rpy2 via conda using default R installation

Tags: linux, r, python-2.7, anaconda, rpy2

I use the Anaconda Python distribution on Ubuntu linux and would like to use R magics in IPython notebooks. Is there a way to install rpy2 with the conda distribution and use my current default R installation at /usr/bin/R? My goal is to keep the current R installation as is without installing R or other R packages via conda.

This [response to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987932/installing-rpy2-on-mac-osx-with-anaconda-python-3-4-and-r-3-1-installed-via-macp) suggests using a recipe for doing so on mac, but doesn't work for me:

```
conda skeleton pypi rpy2
conda build rpy2
conda install rpy2 --use-local
```

The build command yields the follow error:

```
Error: No packages found in current linux-64 channels matching:  singledispatch
```

I can install singledispatch via binstar:

```
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/asmeurer singledispatch

conda list | grep "singledispatch"
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py27_1
```

But I get the same error regarding there being no packages found in current linux-64 channels.

Comment: Possibly a glitch with `conda`. You may want to report it on their tracker. Otherwise `singledispatch` is only required wihen running python 2.7 as it is available in `functools` with Python 3.4. If sticking to Python 2.7, `pip install singledispatch` should get you going.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the package not installing in the proper place, I would recommend instead using apt instead of conda

sudo apt install python-rpy2

edit:
*** note official support for rpy2 has been discontinued for 2.7 ***