# cannot install rpy2 in os x

Tags: python, r

```
airbears2-10-142-34-155:rpy2-2.7.8 clarkkent$ ls
AUTHORS     NEWS        README.rst  rpy     setup.cfg
MANIFEST.in PKG-INFO    doc     rpy2.egg-info   setup.py
airbears2-10-142-34-155:rpy2-2.7.8 clarkkent$ python setup.py install
Error: Tried to guess R's HOME but no command (R) in the PATH.

airbears2-10-142-34-155:rpy2-2.7.8 pitcany$ echo $R_HOME
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/R
```

Yes, I have tried exporting R_HOME and nothing works. Help? What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try using pip instead. I know it seems convoluted, installing one thing to install another, to install what you want, but it works for me.

First, install easy_install:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | sudo python
```

Then use that to install pip:

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

Then use that to install rpy2:

```
sudo pip install rpy2
```

- credit to Pavan on this post for the instructions to install pip:
  [How do I install pip on macOS or OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/installing-pip-on-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

I'd  actually install conda and do conda install. Conda can be pipped as well, but also comes with the Anaconda Python distribution for free. It manages also sorts of dependency stuff very well which can be a huge pain w/ the PyData stack.

[How to install rpy2 via conda using default R installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31392238/how-to-install-rpy2-via-conda-using-default-r-installation)